# how to clear text box when first opened

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, textbox

I have a search function list with a text box on top. The user can enter letters into the text box and the list will get updated after each letter.

For example the user enters "A", then the list will only show trailers containing "A".

The problem I am having is the text box isn't clearing when the user closes the search. When I open up the search again, whatever I entered is still there. I don't know how it is remembering what I entered but how to I clear the text box each time the search is opened?

```
<tr>
    <td class="Header">
        Trailer Type
        <a style="float:right;width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:0px;" title="Pick from list..." class="iconSearch" id="btnShowType"></a>                                            
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTrailerTypeID" Value="0" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTrailerType"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the text box holds the value after you submit the form? Are you submitting the form using javascript?

Comment: @pwee167 no I am not submitting the form. I am just entering values into the textbox, I close the search and open it again, and the text box still have the values in it

Comment: How are you "closing the seach"? Is this a modal or a pop-window?

Comment: Where are your search open and search close buttons? Do you open and close the search from code behind or are you using js/jquery to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the search, seems like you are hiding the search panel(can be a 'div'). That definitely would not clear the fields. For that, you need to either clear it manually when user clicks close button or if you are refreshing page, then on page load.

Here are the solutions to clear it up by jQuery.

1. One of the easy solution is:

   $( "form" )[ 0 ].reset();
2. But if you want to clear inputs fields within an element, you can do this:

   $.fn.cleanUpControls = function() 
       {
           return this.each(function() 
           {
               var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
               if (tag == 'form')
                 return $(':input',this).clearForm();
               if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
                 this.value = '';
           });
       };

   ```
   $('div.searchPanel').cleanUpControls();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Proposed Solution 1:**

In the provider portal, need to set `AutoCompleteType=Disabled` property for all `text boxes` where user enters the sensitive information

**Disadvantage**: This solution may not work in FireFox. Need to test in FireFox and confirm.

**Solution 2:**

This solution works in all browsers.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

**or**

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: No that didn't work. The textbox still has the values in it when I open the search again

Comment: @user123456789 may be that are old values, clear your cache and then try

Comment: No, textbox still remembers values

Answer (score 0):

It's a textbox which won't erase what's typed inside it when you hide it. If you're only hiding it, re-showing it will have what you typed in it before. You need to have some functionality to clear the text when you close it. Hard to suggest what to do with the limited question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of .Net. If you had a pure html it would achieve what you want

```
<input type="text" id="txtTrailerType" />
```

Else just clear it in the round-trip e.g. on Page_Load

```
txtTrailerType.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           txtTrailerType.Text="";
        }
}

May be it helps..

Answer (score 0):

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           txtTrailerType.Text="";
        }
}
```